# How to find why php72_fpm is failing to start on OpenBSD?

Tags: php, openbsd, openbsd-httpd

My httpd logs show errors that look like php-fpm issues and sure enough, when I try

`rcctl start php72_fpm`

I get

> php72_fpm(failed)

In line with other OpenBSD configuration so far, I'd expect to be able to investigate some logs and read some man pages, but not sure where to find the error message in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was to:

Open the rc file at `/etc/rc.d/php72_fpm` to find the actual executable's path:

`/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm-7.2` and running that directly, which gave the actual error:

> failed to load configuration file `/etc/php-fpm.conf`

Running `locate php-fpm.conf` showed an example at `/usr/local/share/examples/php-7.2/php-fpm.conf`

So, the missing step was to manually run the command to get more verbose output of the error, but I didn't know to look in the `rc.d` scripts directory.

Answer (score 3):

By running

```
rcctl -d start php72_fpm
```

(note the `-d`), you will start the service without redirecting the output from the `rc.d` script to `/dev/null`.  This would allow you to see what's happening.

This is me trying to start `php72_fpm` from freshly installed `php-7.2.10` installation.

```
$ doas rcctl -d start php72_fpm
doing _rc_parse_conf
doing _rc_quirks
php72_fpm_flags empty, using default ><
doing _rc_parse_conf /var/run/rc.d/php72_fpm
doing _rc_quirks
doing rc_check
php72_fpm
doing rc_start
doing _rc_wait start
doing rc_check
[04-Nov-2018 23:44:31] WARNING: Nothing matches the include pattern '/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf' from /etc/php-fpm.conf
at line 125.
[04-Nov-2018 23:44:31] ERROR: No pool defined. at least one pool section must be specified in config file
[04-Nov-2018 23:44:31] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[04-Nov-2018 23:44:31] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
doing _rc_rm_runfile
(failed)
```

The issue here is that the configuration is missing.

Make sure that you copy the supplied example configuration file from `/usr/local/share/examples/php-7.2` into `/etc/php-fpm.d` (and modify it to fit your needs).

See also:

- [man rcctl](http://man.openbsd.org/rcctl)
- [man rc.d](http://man.openbsd.org/rc.d)